# Is there a way to do if then else all on one line in vba (visual basic/VB.NET)?

Tags: vb.net, vba, if-statement

I have a series of short "if else" statements I need to do in my code.  Is there a way to do an statement on one line?  I know that visual basic normally accepts line breaks as the next part of the statement, but it would make my code look a lot cleaner in this case if I could get "if then else" all on one line.

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VBA.  Most forms of VB allow multiple statements using `:` as in `If foo Then result = Red: Else Result = Blue`.  it does not however, make the code "cleaner"

Comment: VB.Net is not VBA is not VBScript. If you don't know what language you're actually writing your code in, step away from the keyboard until you figure it out. Stop tag spamming here. They're not the same just because they start with *VB*, any more than a cat and a car and a carrot are all the same because they start with *ca*. Tags have relevance and meaning here; use only the ones you're certain apply to your question, and read the tag description anyway to make sure it means what you think it means.

Comment: Not for nothing but you should read [ask] and take the [tour].  Nearly all your past questions have answers, some have more than one, but none have been accepted.  Accepting answers and up voting posts you find helpful helps other users find good posts..

Comment: please post your code. we will see if it can be cleaned up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I am assuming you are indeed asking about VBA.

In VBA, `If Foo Then Bar Else FooBar` is completely legal and does not even require a statement separator `:`. That would only be required for multiple statements in the if or else branch of the one-line if statment.

Please note however that one-line if statements usually do not make your code more readable, more the opposite.

Comment: If anybody (like me) comes here with the same question in mind: all syntax details needed are explained in Microsoft's documentation: [If...Then...Else statement] [1] (VBA)

  [1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ifthenelse-statement